# Find duplicates in 2D arrays in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want a cod that will find duplicates and return it in separate array.
So I found a code that would be perfect for me, but the thing is that this code is removing duplicates. I thought that it will be a simple job to change it, but somehow I cannot manage to do it....

I was thinking that it will be in this part of code `If Err.Number <> 0 Then coll.Remove txt` but have no idea how to change it. I have tried changing `<>` with `=` but it seems not to work.

Can someone tell me where and how should I change the code  to get duplicates from 2 arrays.

```
Sub test()

Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim arr3 As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim I As Long, j As Long, ii As Long, txt As String, x


With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A2:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("A2:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With
Set coll = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    txt = Join(Array(arr1(I, 1), arr1(I, 2), arr1(I, 3)), Chr(2))
    coll.Add txt, txt
Next I

For I = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
    txt = Join(Array(arr2(I, 1), arr2(I, 2), arr2(I, 3)), Chr(2))
    Err.Clear
    coll.Add txt, txt
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then coll.Remove txt
Next I

ReDim arr3(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 3)

For I = 1 To coll.Count
    x = Split(coll(I), Chr(2))
    For ii = 0 To 2
        arr3(I, ii + 1) = x(ii)
    Next
Next I

Worksheets("test").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr3, 1), 3).Value = arr3
Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Regards,
Timonek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extract Duplicates

- If you set `CountSameWorksheetDuplicates` to `True`, it will return the duplicates of each worksheet even if they are not found in the other worksheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDuplicates()

    Const sName1 As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sCols1 As String = "A:C"
    Const sfRow1 As Long = 2
    
    Const sName2 As String = "Sheet2"
    Const sCols2 As String = "A:C"
    Const sfRow2 As Long = 2

    Const dName As String = "Test"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A2"

    Const CountSameWorksheetDuplicates As Boolean = False
    Dim Delimiter As String: Delimiter = Chr(2)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sData As Variant
    sData = RefColumns(wb.Worksheets(sName1).Rows(sfRow1).Columns(sCols1))
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sKey As Variant
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        sKey = StrJoinedDataRow(sData, r, Delimiter)
        If CountSameWorksheetDuplicates Then
            DictAddCount dict, sKey
        Else
            DictAdd dict, sKey, 1
        End If
    Next r
    
    sData = RefColumns(wb.Worksheets(sName2).Rows(sfRow2).Columns(sCols2))
            
    If CountSameWorksheetDuplicates Then
        For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
            sKey = StrJoinedDataRow(sData, r, Delimiter)
            DictAddCount dict, sKey
        Next r
    Else
        Dim dict2 As Object: Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For r = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
            sKey = StrJoinedDataRow(sData, r, Delimiter)
            DictAdd dict2, sKey
        Next r
        For Each sKey In dict2.Keys
            DictAddCount dict, sKey
        Next sKey
        Set dict2 = Nothing
    End If
    Erase sData
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        If dict(sKey) = 1 Then dict.Remove sKey
    Next sKey
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    r = 0
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        sData = Split(sKey, Delimiter)
        r = r + 1
        For c = 1 To cCount
            dData(r, c) = sData(c - 1)
        Next c
    Next sKey
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dfCellAddress).Resize(drCount, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    drg.Resize(drg.Worksheet.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1) _
        .Offset(drCount).Clear ' clear below
    
    drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the range from the first row of a range
'               ('FirstRowRange') to the row range containing
'               the bottom-most non-empty cell in the row's columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstRowRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' empty range
        Set RefColumns = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a row of a 2D array in a delimited string.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function StrJoinedDataRow( _
    ByVal Data As Variant, _
    ByVal RowIndex As Long, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = " ") _
As String
    Const ProcName As String = "StrJoinedDataRow"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim c As Long
    Dim cString As String
    
    For c = LBound(Data, 2) To UBound(Data, 2)
        cString = cString & CStr(Data(RowIndex, c)) & Delimiter
    Next c
    
    StrJoinedDataRow = Left(cString, Len(cString) - Len(Delimiter))
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds a value ('Key') to a key of an existing ('ByRef')
'               dictionary ('dict') adding another value ('Item')
'               to the key's associated item.
' Remarks:      Error and blank values are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DictAdd( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        ByVal Key As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal Item As Variant = Empty)
    If Not IsError(Key) Then
        If Len(Key) > 0 Then
            dict(Key) = Item
        End If
    End If
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds a value ('Key') to a key of an existing ('ByRef')
'               dictionary ('dict') increasing its count being held
'               in the key's associated item.
' Remarks:      Error and blank values are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DictAddCount( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        ByVal Key As Variant)
    If Not IsError(Key) Then
        If Len(Key) > 0 Then
            dict(Key) = dict(Key) + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: works perfect! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Dict as Object
Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Line As Object
For Each line in MyArray
    On Error Resume Next
    Dict.Add(Line, "")
    On Error Goto 0
Next
```

Dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys. We are only setting keys and ignoring the value by not setting it. The dictionary raises an error if the key exists.

Comment: how should I implement this into code?

Comment: You haven't defined in your question what is a duplicate. Make it a one dimensional array with each element. I put tab delimited strings into a array. When using each element I use the `split function`.

Comment: I`m sorry for that duplicate is when all three elements are the same

Comment: Put each in a tab delimited (or something else if they contain tabs) string and use it as the key. See `split()` and `join()`.

Comment: You forgot to use the `Set` keyword: `Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. `Line` needs to be declared as a variant: `Dim Line As Variant`, although a `For...Next` loop using the array's limits is preferred when looping through the elements of an array. `On Error Resume Next` is kind of a last resort i.e. e.g. `If Dict.Exists(Line) Then` is not that complicated. An even simpler way is `Dict(Line) = ""` (without the If statement) which in this case is useless anyway since you need to count. You could study the dictionary [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).

Comment: It was ported from vbscript (which I lost) to vb.net. Then I attempted to port it back to vbscript (which is compatible with VBA).